# Tengo un inconveniente con la libreria Chart Js con svelte al pasar a produccion

Tags: javascript, chart.js, build, svelte

Al intentar usar Chart js en modo desarollador, la libreria trabaja como se espera, sin embargo al al pasar a produccion con svelte noto que esta libreria deja de funcionar por completo y en la consola del navegador noto que el constructor que se encarga de crear la grafica no lo toma como deberia arrojando los siguientes logs:

*Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: **sm** is not a constructor
at w (index.svelte-f4bd6f82.js:87:83952)*

Donde revisando el código del error, hace referencia al siguiente código ==> **new Chart()**

y no se que configuración debo realizar ademas para evitar que esto suceda...

Agradecería a cualquiera que tenga experiencia al utilizar npm run build o pasar a producción que me pueda colaborar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿En producción usas `HTTPS`? ¿Como estas incluyendo la librería?

Comment: Creo que si, osea yo tengo un front y un backend el cual los tengo conectados 0

Comment: Actualicé el post para que veas que pasa

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir tu `svelte.config.js`? De nuevo, ¿Como estas incluyendo la librería ChartJS? ¿Cual estas usando?

Comment: `import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-node';
import preprocess from 'svelte-preprocess';
//import path from 'path';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
 kit: {
  adapter: adapter()
 },
 preprocess: [
  preprocess({
   postcss: true
  })
 ]
};

export default config;
`

Comment: De chart js estoy usando la ultima , la "chart.js": "^3.9.1", y la manera que indica alli de importar y que tengo importada es: import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';

Comment: Intenta [hacerlo así](https://justpaste.it/3zhg5)